# Arrange points on a regular grid to avoid overplotting

Tags: r, algorithm, ggplot2

Sometimes I want to avoid over-plotting and instead see every single observation in a scatter plot, even if that means some dots are not exactly where their coordinates make them out to be. I wrote the [`ggpointgrid` R package](https://github.com/nevrome/ggpointgrid) to add this functionality to the `ggplot2` infrastructure. Here is an example of this package in action, so `geom_point` vs. `geom_pointgrid`:

```
my_data <- tibble::tibble(
  x = rnorm(500),
  y = rnorm(500),
  value = sample(c("A", "B"), 500, replace = T)
)

ggplot(my_data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = value)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-5, 5), ylim = c(-5, 5))

ggplot(my_data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = value)) +
  ggpointgrid::geom_pointgrid(grid_x = 50, grid_y = 50) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-5, 5), ylim = c(-5, 5))
```

[image]

The arrangement of input points is powered by a core algorithm, which maps the points to a regular grid. It requires the pairwise distances of each grid and each input point and returns a *solid* (certainly not *optimal*) mapping of each input- to one grid-point. I would now like to get some feedback from you on how to make this algorithm faster and more memory-efficient. Is the recursive implementation a good idea or terribly inefficient?

Here's the version of the algorithm I've been working on recently:

```
core_algorithm <- function(distance_long, is_sorted = FALSE) {
  # sort grid-point distance table by distance if it's not already sorted
  if (is_sorted) { distance_long_sorted <- distance_long } else {
    distance_long_sorted <- dplyr::arrange(distance_long, .data[["distance"]])
  }
  # get smallest distance grid point for each input point
  closest_grid_points <- distance_long_sorted[!duplicated(distance_long_sorted$point_id),]
  # find grid point duplicates and create subsets with already uniquely claimed positions
  grid_points_dups <- unique(closest_grid_points$grid_id[duplicated(closest_grid_points$grid_id)])
  has_grid_point_dup <- closest_grid_points$grid_id %in% grid_points_dups
  without_dups <- closest_grid_points[!has_grid_point_dup,]
  with_dups <- closest_grid_points[has_grid_point_dup,]
  # find best input point matches according to distance for duplicated grid points
  with_dups_better <- with_dups[!duplicated(with_dups$grid_id),]
  # combine newly solved point-grid pairs for the output grid
  newly_solved <- dplyr::bind_rows(without_dups, with_dups_better)
  # construct distance table with yet unattributed input and grid points
  new_distance_long <- dplyr::anti_join(
    dplyr::anti_join(distance_long_sorted, newly_solved, by = "grid_id"),
    newly_solved, by = "point_id"
  )
  # decide whether the attribution is ready or not
  if (nrow(new_distance_long) == 0) {
    return(newly_solved)
  } else {
    return(
      dplyr::bind_rows(
        core_algorithm(new_distance_long, is_sorted = T),
        newly_solved
      )
    )
  }
}
```

And here is some test setup to run it:

```
# generate test data
regular_grid <- expand.grid(1:100, 1:100)
points_to_plot <- data.frame(
  x = sample(1:100, 4000, replace = T),
  y = sample(1:100, 4000, replace = T)
)

# calculate pairwise distances of grid and points
distance_matrix <- fields::rdist(regular_grid, points_to_plot)
distance_long <- stats::setNames(
  reshape2::melt(distance_matrix),
  c("grid_id", "point_id", "distance")
)

# run algorithm
core_algorithm(distance_long)
```

You see that I mostly used base R operations with some `dplyr` functions where I found them clearly superior. I'm not strictly committed to this setup, though. Feel free to suggest solutions with other dependencies. And feel also free to point me to other stack-overflow boards, if you find this question misplaced here.

Comment: Not quite sure if I really understand the function, but it seems a bit odd to me that you are defining a function and then using this function within that function (looks like a good recipe for code failure to me). I think you might wanna have a look into `while` for that iterative process (?).

Comment: as for your package, this type of computation is actually what so called "positions" are made for - maybe you wanna create a "position" instead. see https://ggplot2-book.org/extensions.html#new-positions A great package which I'd recommend you to have a look into (it actually does similar stuff as your package and implements new positions) is for example ggbeeswarm.

Comment: Iteratively row-binding works logically but scales horribly (see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)). I suggest combining tyour returns into a `list` and row-binding (`bind_rows`) _once_ once your recursive process is complete.

Comment: Thanks for tip about row binding. Avoiding that seems indeed a good way to speed things up. If I understand this blog post (https://win-vector.com/2015/07/27/efficient-accumulation-in-r/) correctly, then in place mutation should be the fastest way to accumulate the results. This should be possible, as the size of the output table is known from the beginning.
"positions" may be a better way to integrate the feature with ggplot2. Didn't know about that. Thanks for making me aware.

Comment: After reading the relevant copy-on-modify section of Advanced R (https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#copy-on-modify) I feel this is harder than I hoped it would be. Maybe I should indeed rewrite the algorithm in C++.